# Only uppercased UITextField Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I want to force UITextField input to uppercased text. This is what I did:

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    let nsString = textField.text as NSString?
    let newString = nsString?.replacingCharacters(in: range, with: string)
    textField.text = newString?.uppercased()
    return false
}
```

Is there any way to force uppercase UITextField without using `replacingCharacterInRange` of `NSString`?

Answer (score 4):

I found it!

I just added a target to my TextField of type `UIControlEvents.editingChanged`
And in the selector I did: `textField.text = textField.text?.uppercased()`

Here is the code:

```
myTextField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(myTextFieldTextChanged), for: UIControlEvents.editingChanged)

func myTextFieldTextChanged (textField: UITextField) {
    textField.text =  textField.text?.uppercased()
}
```

This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks every one!

Answer (score 2):

It's very easy, just do this

`self.yourTexField.autocapitalizationType = UITextAutocapitalizationType.AllCharacters;`

Comment: this is for keyboard, I want the text to be uppercased.